# Oracle MAF - Not able to open application

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, oracle-maf

I am new to Oracle MAF. I am using OEPE.
In Oracle MAF I try to run example of “Employee”, but somehow it display only launcher page only. Please guide me to resolve this issue.  Here with I attached the screen shot of application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDbxc.png)

Comment: Oracle TechNet has a forum dedicated to Mobile Application Framework. I suggest you ask your question there, because that's where experts hang out. [Find it here](https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-mobile/oraclemaf)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It was OEPE version issue.I installed latest version and the problem is resolved.Now I am able to open application.